# Wordpress Plugin redirect

Tags: php, wordpress

So I have a wordpress plugin that transforms a bracket like

```
[randomurl]
```

into an

```
<a href="/wp-content/plugins/randomurl/random.php">Random</a>
```

tag. As I'm new to plugin programming for wordpress I don't know if there's a better way to do so, but I'm open to other solutions. In the random.php file a random url is chosen and the user is referred to this url. (I can't put the url directly into the a-tag, because it needs to load a list every time). The random.php looks something like this:

```
<?php
$content = file_get_contents('http://example.com/urls.php');
$urls = json_decode($content);
$theURL = $urls[rand(0,10)];
header('Location: '.$theURL);
?>
```

The problem is that due to the rewrite rules from wordpress I can't access the random.php. Is there a better way to do all this? Do I have to disable the rewrite engine?

Comment: Rewrite rules will not prevent you from accessing that file, if it actually exists.  However, I strongly, strongly, *strongly* recommend against providing a url to a file within your plugin.  Instead, bring that functionality into your site in the plugin, and call that function.

Comment: Thanks, can you give me a link or any help how to do this?

Comment: What does the link do? What's the purpose / content of random.php?

Comment: it loads a collection (that is changing every time) of links from another server. as i guess at most 1% of the visitors will click this link i don't want to load the links every time the page is opened.

Comment: And what do you do with the links? Display them?

Comment: no, i redirect the user to the link using header('Location: '.$link);

Comment: Please be clear.  Are you saying that you: (1) Load the info from random.php, which (2) redirects the user to a url, using header()?  Why wouldn't you just display the random link in the <a> element in the first place, rather than this gyration?

Comment: That's correct.
I can't put the link into the a element directly because random.php gets the link itself from another server and I think loading the link from another server every time someone opens the page would slow down the page. So I thought providing the link only when the user clicks on it would be more efficient.

Comment: Then do this: (1) In your plugin, make the link load the blog url, with a paremeter in the url: `www.myblog.com/?random=true` - then (2) in your plugin, in an `init` action, watch for `$_GET['random']`, and if it's set, then (3) do the work that you're doing in random.php (don't call / load random.php, move the function(s) to do the work there, including your header() redirect)

Comment: @cale_b- what's wrong with providing a url to a file within your plugin?